# I have to put a 2D array of 30*126 to tflite model. How to convert a 2D array of float to ByteBuffer in java

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, multidimensional-array, tensorflow-lite

I’m Nguyen, a Vietnamese high school student who is working on a sign language translation app project using computer vision and AI.
In my app, I used LSTM model, when converted to tflite model I saw this sample code:

```
try {
    SignLangModel model = SignLangModel.newInstance(context);

    // Creates inputs for reference.
    TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 30, 126}, DataType.FLOAT32);
    inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);

    // Runs model inference and gets result.
    SignLangModel.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);
    TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();

    // Releases model resources if no longer used.
    model.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Handle the exception
}
```

This is what my 2d array looks like

```
[[ 0.62733257,  0.44471735, -0.69024068, ...,  0.40363967, 0.28696212, -0.06274992],
 [ 0.62688404,  0.4438577 , -0.73676074, ...,  0.40629318, 0.28771287, -0.05781016],
 [ 0.62661999,  0.44294813, -0.7216031 , ...,  0.40591961, 0.28609812, -0.06014785],
...
 [ 0.62216419,  0.43501934, -0.69985718, ...,  0.38580206, 0.29433241, -0.05569796]]
```

I wondering how to convert 2D float array to ByteBuffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the conversion as it is shown here:

```
public byte[] ToByteArray(float[,] nmbs)
    {
        byte[] nmbsBytes = new byte[nmbs.GetLength(0) * nmbs.GetLength(1)*4];
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nmbs.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nmbs.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                byte[] array = BitConverter.GetBytes(nmbs[i, j]);
                for (int m = 0; m < array.Length; m++)
                {
                    nmbsBytes[k++] = array[m];
                }
            }
        }
        return nmbsBytes;
    }
```

using of course floats wherever the code has bytes...and then

```
floar[] array = returnedArrayfromAbove;
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(array);
```

BUT I think you can follow the TensorFlow Lite guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference) using the appropriate dependencies in your build.gradle file and then:

```
try (Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter(file_of_a_tensorflowlite_model)) {
  interpreter.run(input, output);
}
```

using `Interpreter.run()` where you can input directly your 2D array.
Generally the `Interpreter.run()` method will give you more flexibility than the generated code from AS. You can find many examples for using Interpreter directly [there](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples)

Tag me if you need more help.

Comment: thanks a lot :> could you please tell me more about the BitConverter?

Comment: Leave it and try Interpreter.run... I do not think you will have a good result with ByteBuffer. You can use array for input and output. Interpreter.run(inputArray, outputArray)

Comment: ummm when I initialize the Interpreter, it says 
`Missing method body, or declare abstract
Invalid method declaration; return type required`
although I have imported dependencies:
`import com.example.mainfinal.ml.SignLangModel;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter;`

Comment: use code examples from the official android apps. It should be straightforward.

Comment: I don't have much experience with TensorFlow lite so I have quite a lot of problems hope you don't mind :( so what is the data type of the output and how to predict and print the label from that output :(

Comment: I understand.. I really do not have time to review code. I suggest you spend some time getting in touch with the tensorflow lite guide. There are a lot of options. Use code from an example to init the Interpreter and then run with input and output array.